DAP does not see my config for javascript
I get that error: No configuration found for "javascript". You need to add configs to "dap.configurations.javascript" (See ":h dap-configuration")
plugins/debugger.lua:
  return {
    {
      "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
      dependencies = {
        { "rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui", dependencies = { "mfussenegger/nvim-dap", "nvim-neotest/nvim-nio" } },
        "theHamsta/nvim-dap-virtual-text",
      },
      { "Joakker/lua-json5", run = "./install.sh" },
      -- "mxsdev/nvim-dap-vscode-js",
      { "microsoft/vscode-js-debug" },

  config = function()
    local dap = require("dap")
    local dapui = require("dapui")

    require("craftzdog.debugger-def")
    require("craftzdog.debugger")

    require("dap").setup()

    require("nvim-dap-virtual-text").setup()
    require("dapui").setup()

    require("dap.ext.vscode").json_decode = require("json5").parse
    require("dap.ext.vscode").load_launchjs()

    dap.listeners.before.attach.dapui_config = function()
      dapui.open()
    end
    dap.listeners.before.launch.dapui_config = function()
      dapui.open()
    end
    dap.listeners.before.event_terminated.dapui_config = function()
      dapui.close()
    end
    dap.listeners.before.event_exited.dapui_config = function()
      dapui.close()
    end
  end,
},
  }

craftzdog/debugger.lua:
local dap = require("dap")

dap.configurations.javascript = {
  {
    type = "pwa-node",
    request = "launch",
    name = "Launch file",
    program = "${file}",
    cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
  },
}

craftzdog/debugger-ref.lua:
require("dap").adapters["pwa-node"] = {
  type = "server",
  host = "localhost",
  port = "${port}",
  executable = {
    command = "node",
    --  Make sure to update this path to point to your installation
    args = { "/share/debug-servers/js-debug/src/dapDebugServer.js", "${port}" },
  },
}

I already tried to transfer the code from is files into one but it didn’t work.I also tried loading config files after DAP initialization
